# Creating a map by iterating through a list in pygame?

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame, 2d

I am creating my first game with pygame and am trying to render a maze by using a list where it creates an tile where the designated number is. Where the index reads 1, it'll print a wall, 2, a door, and so on. Right now I just have it so that it prints the same image for every tile, but the draw() function is only picking up and printing when the index hits 1.

```py
class Maze:
    def __init__(self, x=20, y=20):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tile = pygame.image.load("assets/redsquare.png")
        self.tile = pygame.transform.scale(self.tile, (20, 20))
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 700))
        self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
        self.maze =  """ 
                         1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                         1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
                         1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                         1 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 
                         1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 4 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 
                         1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 4 0 0 1 
                         1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 4 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
                         1 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
                         1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 1 
                         1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 
                         1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 
                         1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
                         1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
                         1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 """
        self.maze = self.maze.splitlines()
```

And this is my draw function.

```
def draw(self):
    print(self.maze)
    for y, line in enumerate(self.maze):
        for x, c in enumerate(line):
            if c == "1":
                self.screen.blit(self.tile, (x * 20, y * 20))
            if c == "2":
                self.screen.blit(self.tile, (x * 20, y * 20))
            if c == "3":
                self.screen.blit(self.tile, (x * 20, y * 20))
            if c == "4":
                self.screen.blit(self.tile, (x * 20, y * 20))
```

Comment: Hi, I hate to be a nitpicker, but shouldn't your 'def __init__' be indented? It is a part of the class. Also, it looks like your code is doing as designed. It does the exact same thing for cases 1 through 4. What happens when you run it? Lastly, I would advice using if/elif in these cases, since the cases are mutually exclusive, and it would be more efficient and readable

Answer (score 0):

The maze string contains a lot of whitespaces, thus you don't get the expected result.

I recommend to create a list of strings, where each string represents a single row of the grid:
(You don't need `splitlines` at all)

```py
self.maze = ["12111111111111111111", 
             "10100000400000000001", 
             "10101110101111111111", 
             "10401000100000000401", 
             "10111011111111101101", 
             "10100010004000101101", 
             "14111110111110111101", 
             "10001000400010104001", 
             "11101011111010101101", 
             "10001010401010101101", 
             "11101010101010101101", 
             "10001000101010101101", 
             "14111111101010001101", 
             "10000040101111111111", 
             "11111010101000400011", 
             "10001010101011111011", 
             "10111010100010001003", 
             "10000010111110101011", 
             "11111010000000101011", 
             "11111111111111111111"]
```

---

Alternatively you can replace all blanks by "nothing" (`.replace(" ", "")`):

```py
self.maze =  """ 
              1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
              1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
              1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
              1 0 4 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 
              1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 4 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 
              1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 4 0 0 1 
              1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 4 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 
              1 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
              1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 1 
              1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 
              1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 
              1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
              1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
              1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 """
self.maze = self.maze.replace(" ", "").splitlines()
```